# Are there invariants of formal group laws other than height?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, group-schemes, formal-groups

By a theorem of Lazard, 1-d formal group laws over separably closed fields of char $p$ are classified up to isomorphism by their height.

Are there invariants of formal group laws other than height (and the characteristic of their underlying field) that are not isomorphism invariants?

---

I've been informed that if k is algebraically closed and char p, then elliptic curves are classified by the j-invariant.

Lazard's theorem says that their associated FormalGrpLaws are isomorphic to the unique 1-dimensional FormalGrpLaw of height 1 or of height 2 (the Honda formal group law).

So there are certainly more EllipticCurve/k than FormalGrpLaw/k!

Besides, say, distinguishing between a singular and supersingular elliptic curve, what properties of the original group scheme $G \to \text{Spec}  R$ are recoverable after choosing a concrete isomorphism $G \simeq \text{Spf }R[[t]]$?

Comment: A more general classification is in terms of Dieudonne modules (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dieudonn%C3%A9_module). I don't know much about this, but see https://math.berkeley.edu/~aaron/xkcd/dieudonne-modules.pdf for an exposition. Over a non-algebraically closed field the classification involves Galois cohomology.

Comment: Just noticed this. I guess you’re aware that for each $p$, there are only finitely many supersingular values of $j$. This is a corner of the topic of the relationship between elliptic curves and formal groups that I’m far from an expert in, but maybe I can help you a little, if you’re still interested in the topic. Don’t hesitate to e-mail me.